# Remove .html extension from URLs in Windows Server

Tags: web-hosting, iis-8, windows-server-2012

I have a website hosted on GoDaddy and I just realized they use Windows Servers not Apache.  Which means using an .htaccess file doesn't work.

I want to remove the .html and .php extension from all website URLs.

Basically, the question is:   How do you re-write this (which would go in the .htaccess file) for a Windows Server?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: if its your hosting shared linux, than try this tutorial, http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/02/godaddy-remove-php-extension/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solved it!

You can accomplish this by creating a web.config file with the following code:

```
<configuration>   
 <system.webServer>   
    <rewrite>          
        <rules>             
            <rule name="RewriteHTML">
              <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">                     
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />                     
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />                 
                </conditions>                 <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.html" />             
            </rule>                
        </rules>      
    </rewrite>   
 </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

Comment: yeah there support didnt know the solution lol this worked fine good job

Comment: this worked for a day, in my case. After that stopped working out of nowhere

Comment: Found a slight bug that will fail the configtest (.\httpd -t on windows from Apache bin directory).  match needs to have an end tag around entire condition and action tags.
...
<match url="(.*)">
<conditions....
<add...
<add...
</conditions>
<action...
</match>